# Can't get past character creation

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-ii-daggerfall

I have just started playing Daggerfall, but I can't get past creating my character.

This is where I am up to:
[image: You must distribute your bonus points.]

I have tried pressing everything but I can't continue.  What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During character creation, you have a pool of "bonus" attribute points to spend as you wish.  (This is the "8" currently next to your INT score.)  You must spend all of your bonus points before you can continue creating your character.

To do so, click on an attribute; the little selector (where the "8" is showing in your screenshot) will move to that attribute.  You can then assign bonus points to it by clicking the upwards-facing triangle above the number of bonus points.  If you change your mind about bonus points already spent, you can reselect that attribute and use the downwards-facing triangle to remove points, but you can't go below the starting value.

**TL;DR:**  Select an attribute, click the up-triangle, and repeat until the number between the triangles is 0.  You should then be able to get on with the game.